# A fix for CS0426 in XAML and generated .g.cs file while building

Tags: c#, xaml

[Error Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWFKA.png)

[Inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyHHZ.png)

[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Q9z.png)

While working on a project I started debugging and out of no where a bunch of CS0426 errors came out of nowhere in the generated .g.cs files. I checked my references and I see all the assemblies referenced and added to the project already as you can see in the images. I have already tried reinstalling VS2019, restarting my computer, reinstalling/updating dotnet to 4.8 and tried a new project solution file as well.

Looking closer I do not know how it cannot find for example "Window" in "System.Windows" especially that is included in that type. All my 'usings' are in tact as well. I believe this pops up when I created multiple classes in a solution as well.

Any idea on how to fix this? I am using Visual Studio 2019 and DotNet 4.8.

Direct class initialization works without using the assembly names but it contradicts not being able to find it within the assembly and the generated file uses the assembly name to initialize the class anyway

[image: Direct class initialization works without using the assembly names but it contradicts not being able to find it within the assembly and the generated file uses the assembly name to initialize the class anyway]

Comment: have you tried closing VS, deleting the files and reopen VS and regenerate? sometimes generated files give us these problems

Comment: Yep I've opened the file folder and deleted the generated the files again it came out to be the same error. I think those files are regenerated every time as well.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all the objects in your MainWindow and then re-compiling?

Comment: Yep it still generated the .g.cs file the same during a build/debug. I added another photo to help understand the problem as well.

Comment: Why does it have System.Windows.Window window; and next line just Window window2;?  Why is there a window2?

Comment: All fixed. Turns out I created a System.cs file that overwrote the using statement's reference.